# Meteor package file inclusion

Tags: meteor

I want to build a meteor package to wrap an existing javascript library. I would like to include the library as a git submodule. I only need 2 files from the submodule. If I only include these two in package.js will the rest of the files be ignored by meteor and not built into the package?

Answer (score 0):

The only files that will end up in your package are those that will be explicitly added with `api.addFiles` routine ([look here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles)).

BTW, If you're planning to wrap an existing JavaScript library then you should probably start by getting familiar with [autopublish](http://autopublish.meteor.com) project. For more details [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIxZnOtWUUY&index=6&list=PLTUf4ytkmI8TtOEISc4qo4m43E8Vf9DJy).